# One view exclude another when a drop occurs

Tags: android, drag-and-drop

I've been struggling on the last couple of days with this program. The issue that I'm facing is about a drop event of a view which excludes another view. What the program is supposed to do is, on a click of a button, creates as many ImageButtons and they all can be dragged and dropped anywhere on the screen. However, he creates the first view and creates the second, but when I drag the second ImageButton, the first one created is deleted from the screen.

Here is the XML

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/relative_main"
    tools:context=".WhyItActivity" >

<Button 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="add button"
    android:onClick="addButton"  />
 </RelativeLayout>
```

Below is the java activity responsible

```
public class WhyItActivity extends Activity {

private RelativeLayout relative;
private LayoutParams params;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_why_it);

    params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    relative = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.relative_main);

    // all the screen be a dropping area
    relative.setOnDragListener(new View.OnDragListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onDrag(View view, DragEvent event) {

            View dragView = (View) event.getLocalState();
            RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) view;

            switch (event.getAction()) {
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
                break;
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
                break;
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:
                break;
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:

                int right = (int)event.getX(); 
                int top = (int)event.getY(); 
                params.setMargins(right, top, 0, 0);
                layout.removeView(dragView);
                layout.addView(dragView, params);
                // set back the visibility
                dragView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                break;

            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }

            return true;
        }
    });
}

/** OnClick */
public void addButton(View v){
    // params for centralizing the image button
    LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);
    // new object
    ImageButton imgBtn = new ImageButton(this);
    imgBtn.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher));
    relative.addView(imgBtn, params);
    // letting the view be dragged around the screen
    imgBtn.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
            ClipData data = ClipData.newPlainText("", "");
            DragShadowBuilder builder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(view);
            view.startDrag(data, builder, view, 0);
            // let the view be invisible while dragging the object
            view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            return true;
        }
    });

}
```

So, the question is... Where I'm screwing? I create a new object, if it's was a matter of just one view on the screen it would be working just fine.

Thanks for reading so far, and possibly be able to help.

Comment: It seems all your new views are stacking on previous ones.

Comment: Man, you're pretty right!! The views are not being deleted, they're being stacked. But, I still can't understand why :(

Comment: There you are, i've posted the answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One silly but critical mistake.

Add this line

```
params = params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

Above

```
params.setMargins(right, top, 0, 0);
```

As u can see there is only one instance of LayoutParam you have been assigning to all your views, thus ending up in stack of views.

Please mark as ***accepted*** if resolved. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Damn what a hell of a mistake! I'm owing you!